# Is there anyway to store folder Content in a .JSON file variable?

Tags: arrays, json, survey

i am completely new to JSON and Java in General.
i have a Task with a similar Block of code:

```
{
    "name": "Chew Barka",
    "breed": "Bichon",
    "age": "2 years",
    "weight": 8,
    "bio": "The park, The pool or the Playground - I love to go anywhere!",
    "filename": ""
},
```

And i would like to have the Contents of the folder:
"C:/Temp" for example
Stored in "filename"
so that when i call "filename" i get the "C:/Temp" Content

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript object notation

Comment: You have both Java and JavaScript tags - these are *two different languages*. JSON is independent - it's a serialisation format just like XML is. It's only text.

Comment: oh, so you can only store data as Text in it.
i changed the Tags just now

Comment: The name JavaScript is the worst idea in the history of programming, makes a lot of people confused.

Comment: as a beginner, i couldnt agree more